# Analytics for pure AS3 Adobe AIR for mobile project?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, google-analytics, analytics

I've been digging around for days looking for a way to do analytic tracking in a pure AS3 Adobe AIR for mobile project. Does anyone have a solution?

I've tried looking at gaforflash http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/
but it looks like AIR isn't supported: 
http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/wiki/Roadmap (see comments)

I've tried looking at http://www.appanalyticshq.com/
But this looks to be Flex dependent. 
http://getsatisfaction.com/app_analytics/topics/where_can_i_get_a_flash_pro_swc

I also looked at straight up Google Analytics http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/home.html
But it says on this page: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingIntro.html
"Note: Currently, Flash tracking is available for any Flash content embedded in a web page. Tracking of data sent from Adobe Air, Shockwave, or via the Flash IDE (e.g. using Test Movie) is not supported at this time."

Anything else out there? Has anyone got this to work?

Comment: i'm using http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/ for Air applications, and there are just some data which is not available on the GA at the end. But mainly it is working.

Comment: I'm trying that right now. What data isn't working?

Comment: Browser and OS version, from main list.

Comment: i'm also using it - no problems so far

Comment: Jevgenij, thanks for the tip! I was able to get it working as well. I can see OS working in the report, but it didn't give me enough detail so I'm tracking this, and it gives me all I want to know: var os:String = Capabilities.os;
   m.tracker.trackEvent( "OS", "run", os);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank Jevgenij and pkyeck.

I was able to get GA working with my project and I verified it is working on both iphones and on Android.

See this example: http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/

Answer (score 1):

you can get free google analytics ane from http://www.devactionscript.com/. This one is based on the latest Google Analytics SDK v3

Answer (score 0):

you can consider gaforflash obsolete and legacy

there is a new library
Google Universal Analytics for ActionScript 3.0

as3-universal-analytics v0.8

https://github.com/zwetan/as3-universal-analytics/releases/tag/0.8

full support for: Flash Player, AIR, Redtamarin
it just works everywhere or almost everywhere :)

for example

```
var config:Configuration = new Configuration();
    config.forcePOST = true;
var tracker:WebTracker = new WebTracker( "UA-12345-67", config );
    tracker.pageview( "/hello/world", "Hello World" );
```